# Why does this Unicode character get mishandled when I ssh in from a different remote server?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty, r

Normally I ssh into a computing cluster from my work machine running OpenSUSE and submit a bash script to a condor queuing system that runs an R program.

When I ssh in from my Windows 10 laptop running Putty and do the exact same thing, the result is very slightly different. In particular, I use R to make a plot that uses the solar symbol ("☉"), which comes out fine when sshing in from my work computer, but comes out as "`<U+0298>`" when sshing in from my laptop.

Why? I don't understand at all how this is even possible.

Comment: The "solar symbol" you pasted into your Question is Unicode code point U+2609, "SUN". The Unicode code point that that gets displayed on the laptop (U+0298) is a similar-looking dot-in-a-circle glyph, "LATIN LETTER BILABIAL CLICK" from the IPA extensions (International Phonetic Alphabet). Are you sure your R-generated plot uses U+2609? Is there any chance you accidentally selected U+0298 when creating the R program? Maybe the only problem here is that your laptop's terminal emulator isn't configured for Unicode or doesn't have access to a fallback font that contains IPA characters.

Comment: The R program indeed uses '\u0298' to create the solar symbol. I do not understand, however, why my terminal editor should have anything to do with this? The script is submitted to a queuing system that runs the code remotely. All I do from my laptop is "condor_submit run_r_script.job", which causes "Rscript script.R" to be run on a remote computing cluster. (I'll try to reconfigure my terminal editor to fix this particular problem, but I would like to also learn from this experience.)

Comment: I said emulator (like PuTTY), not editor (like vim); significant difference. Also, is the plot it creates an image file, or is it drawn via terminal characters? I was assuming it was drawn in the terminal, which would explain how Windows and PuTTY might would be using a different Unicode engine and default font, and may not be able to find a glyph for U+0298, whereas your OpenSUSE Linux system has a completely different Unicode engine, set of installed fonts, terminal emulator, etc., so it might be able to find a glyph for U+0298.

Comment: It creates a pdf file using cairo

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the setting of the LANG environment variable on each of your ssh sessions. I found that if LANG wasn't set to "en_US.UTF-8" then I would get '..' displayed in my plot rather than the Greek mu symbol that I wanted.